# It is correct to set the equal id's in different xml files?

Tags: android, android-layout

For ex. I have 2 Activities.

1. In first: `setContentView(R.layout.activity_first);`
2. In second `setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);`

`activity_first.xml` contain `View` with id  `android:id="@+id/my_view"`, and `activity_second.xml` contain another `View`. To that  `View` I can set the same id (`android:id="@+id/my_view"`) and all works great.

But the way to set equal id's in different xml files correct? May be I miss some google post about that situation?

Comment: I think its fine as in setContentView we already describe which activity uses which xml. So its not big thing to use same name in different xml's.

Answer (score 0):

There is no harm in setting the same ids to different views as long as they are not in the same view. From the [developers site](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html#id),

**An ID need not be unique throughout the entire tree, but it should be unique within the part of the tree you are searching** (*which may often be the entire tree, so it's best to be completely unique when possible*).

It is recommended that you use different ids for different layouts. On the long run, when you will have a lot of layouts and a lot of ids it will get very complicated to differentiate them.

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem with same id.It will work properly. But for a good programming this habit is bad.